# Terraform Providers for Root and Child module confusion

Tags: terraform

I am writing this in the deepest level of frustration after spending a whole day after being around the entire internet.

I am using Terraform with a local provider (as I am on Apple M2 laptop and this provider doesn't have it puiblished, so had to build the package and store locally)

**main.tf**

```
terraform {
  required_providers { 
    runscope = {
      source = "sport24ru/runscope"
      version = "0.10.0"
    }
  }
}
provider "runscope" {
  access_token = var.access_token
}
```

**runscope.tf**

```
module "runscope" {
  source                      = "./runscope"
  product                     = "runscope"
  access_token                = var.access_token
}
```

**terraform apply** and I get the following:

> Error: Failed to query available provider packages
> Could not retrieve the list of available versions for provider hashicorp/runscope: provider registry registry.terraform.io does not have a provider named registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/runscope
> Did you intend to use sport24ru/runscope? If so, you must specify that source address in each module which requires that provider. To see which modules are currently depending on hashicorp/runscope,
> │ run the following command:
> │    terraform providers

I have tried a few things from various documentation/posts, none of them working (spent too much time on it to remember the exact trail):

- Added provider block in the **runscope.tf file** - same error as above
- Used **alias** under the provider block in main.tf file, and I got this:

> The local name "runscope.main" in the root module represents provider "sport24ru/runscope", but "runscope" in module.runscope represents "hashicorp/runscope".
> Each provider has its own distinct configuration schema and provider types, so this module's "runscope" can be assigned only a configuration for hashicorp/runscope, which is not required by module.runscope.

It doesn't have to be this complicated to be honest. I am sure something very obvious is being missed here but I have the mother of all tunnel visions.

What do I do next?

Help would be really appreciated.

PS: This is the snippet of the set up. Each new thing I tried sorta got me more confused and the documentation nor guides are helping me. I only have one provider and I want each child module to re-use it. I have another project with a Hashicorp provider where I don't need to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try adding this to your runscope module files (`./runscope`):

```
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 1.0.0"
  required_providers {
    runscope = {
      source = "sport24ru/runscope"
      version = "0.10.0"
    }
  }
}
```

And then also modify runscope module call:

```
module "runscope" {
  source                      = "./runscope"
  product                     = "runscope"
  access_token                = var.access_token
  providers = {
    runscope = runscope
  }
}
```

Comment: I get the error: A module may have only one required providers configuration. The required providers were previously configured at runscope.tf:3,3-21.

Comment: @Sean sounds like you already had a `terraform {}` block in your runscope module files. Could you share it if that's so?

Comment: I get that error after I added it. The error is coming from runscope file but the duplicate is at the main.tf file